# Apscheduler run job every weekday on specific time range

Tags: python, cron, scheduler, apscheduler

I have a current `apscheduler` that runs the job `mon-fri` and an interval of `~4 mins` all day long. Is it possible to run the job for a specific time range? Lets say from `9:00 am to 5:00 pm` in this case?

My expression looks like this:

```
scheduler.add_job(feed_data, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', minute='*/3', jitter=30)
```

Is it possible to add `start/end datetime` to this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `hour='9-17'` to accomplish that.

Comment: I am setting the timezone as `scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone='Asia/Karachi')` for the jobs. Will the `cron` run for my server clock, i.e `9-17 hour` on server, or will it consider my specified `scheduler timezone`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple answer:-

```
    scheduler.add_job(
    func=lambda: monday_break_scheduler(),
    trigger=CronTrigger(day_of_week='mon', hour=17, minute=40)
    )
```

also import this

```
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
```